# Custom CSS Menu Template Assistance

Tags: css

I have a top menu that I want to remove the padding but unsure exactly what code I need to put into my custom CSS to get the result I am after.

After going into the Development Tools I am left with the following code which I cant seem to get into Custom CSS

```
<div class="menu-block">
 <div class="gf-menu-device-container responsive-type-panel"></div>
  <ul class="gf-menu l1">
   <li class="item101 active last"
     padding-left: 5px;
     padding-right: 7px; ">
```

So as you can see I have changed the padding of left and right for the li class item, however I don't know what to put in the Custom CSS file to achieve this.

Comment: Note that your way for defining styles for that `li` element is wrong. You should instead use `<li class="..." style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 7px;"></li>`

Comment: so what is the code I need for the Custom-CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the `li` tag and If you want to target it specifically, use this:

```
ul.gf-menu li.item101.active.last
{
   padding-left: 5px; 
   padding-right: 7px;
}
```

To target all list elements.

```
ul.gf-menu li
{
   padding-left: 5px; 
   padding-right: 7px;
}
```

Comment: do you know what I can use to effect all the menu items at once? and this did work thank you

Comment: for some reason targeting all doesn't work and if I target them 1 by 1 only the first one will change

Comment: You need to post your full HTML code so we can help :)